# How can I solve this by induction?

Tags: induction, roots

The statement: $ \root{n} \of{n} + \frac{1}{n} < 2$ where $n>2$

My partial solution(?):

$ \root{n+1} \of{n+1} + \frac{1}{n+1} < 2$

$ \root{n+1} \of{n+1}(n+1) + 1 < 2(n+1)$

$ \root{n+1} \of{(n+1)^{n+2}} + 1 < 2n+2$

$ \root{n+1} \of{(n+1)^{n+2}} < 2n+1$

$ (n+1)^{n+2} < (2n+1)^{n+1}$

And I'm stuck. Would appreciate some help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really need induction, you just need the inequality $(1+x)^n\gt1+nx$ for $n\gt1$ (which, if you like, can be proved by induction), from which it follows that

$$\left(2-{1\over n}\right)^n=\left(1+{n-1\over n}\right)^n\gt1+n\cdot{n-1\over n}=n$$

which implies $2-{1\over n}\gt\sqrt[n]n$.

Comment: Barry. Nice answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But there is a power and in your explanation, where there would be a root. Is $(1+x)^n\gt1+nx$ also applicable to  $\root{n} \of{(1+x)}\gt1+nx$ ?

Comment: @GeTo FYI, please see [Bernoulli's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality), which mentions several variations of it which are applicable to what you're asking about.

Comment: @JohnOmielan, thanks for adding that. I should have qualified the statement of the inequality in my answer with the condition $x\gt0$ (which is satisfied by $(n-1)/n$).